# scrollViewDidEndDecelerating is not getting called

Tags: iphone, call, uiscrollviewdelegate

I have a UIScrollView that contains large images and am using paging to scroll between images. In order to save memory, I am loading only one image before and after the currently visible one and loading/releasing new images after a scroll has completed. The problem occurs when one scrolls quickly and scrollViewDidEndDecelerating is not called.
When the scrollViewDidEndDecelerating is called I wanted to display the image name in the active page.

How do I solve this? Why does this happens?

Comment: How are you implementing the scrolling if you're not changing offsets?

I've done this a number of times in different apps, and everything you describe can be achieved with the "normal" approach (scrollRectToVisible), and just intelligently enabling / disabling the animation part depending on the effect you want to achieve. It sounds like you're doing something very unusual here?

Comment: You got any answer for this i have same problem...

Answer (score 1):

**scrollViewDidEndDragging will call after each scroll complete**

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate{}
```

**scrollViewDidEndDecelerating don't call in each drag (if you don't drag with acce speed after draged stop it will don't never call this func)**

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{}
```

**scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation if you want move the scroll view use api not with drag, this api will called.**

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{}
```

Answer (score 0):

Im doing the same thing with a scroll view - lazy loading of images. We actually had to load a thumbnail that is stretched (making a blurry low res version of the image) and then load the real image when the page is actually being displayed 100% in view.

What I had to do was use the following code in the scrollViewDidScroll:scrollView.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{    
    if (!_isCurrentlyRotating) {
        CGFloat pageWidth = _scrollView.frame.size.width;
        int page = floor((_scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth)+1;

        if (_currentPage != page)
            [self setCurrentPage:page];
    }
}
```

The above calculates the page that is going to be displayed (as your scrolling). It will actually change the current page number when the page view is 50% displayed. This can be used in conjunction with the page control to highlight the current page dot.

Using the above, (with paging enabled on the scroll view) when the user uses their finger to change the page (the normal behavior) scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:scrollView is called when the page is 100% displayed. By 100% I mean you can only see one page not part of one part of another.

But we have a 'Start Over' button at the end of the scroll view that calls my scrollToPage: function.

```
- (void) scrollToPage:(int)page {
    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * page;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;
    [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
}
```

Using scrollRectToVisible:animated: method does not trigger the scrollViewDidEndDecelerating: method so I simply added the sharpen method (which simply loads te high res image in the image view) call to both methods so that it will be called if the user scrolls or if the start over button is pressed.

```
- (void) scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    [self sharpenImageView];
}

- (void) scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    [self sharpenImageView];
}
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Check if your `UIScrollView`'s delegate is set or not, or was set to nil.

Normally set in this way `scrollView.delegate = self`.

Answer (score -1):

`scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:` is not meant to do your page layout in. You should implement `scrollViewDidScroll:` and calculate the currently visible page(s) based on the `contentOffset` of the scroll view. If the visible range has changed, add views for the pages that were previously not visible and remove those that are no longer visible.

Comment: This did not help me in finding solution for my problem.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes just clean your project and re-run

Shift & Cmd & K
Shift & Cmd & Alt & k